# How to disable logs?

Tags: raspbian, linux, logfiles

How do I **permanently** disable all logs that appear in `/var/log/`? I tried "service rsyslog stop", "systemctl disable rsyslog" but it still logs stuff because I type "sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=1s" and it deletes 5.7M of logs each time I reboot.

Comment: why do you need to disable logging?

Comment: would certainly not recommend disabling all logging, if you feel like the logs are taking up too much space, adjust logrotate config files to do so. But in their default state, they are already going to be rotating logs out as they become "old" so usually there is nothing you need to do, your filesystem is not going to fill up due to this logging.

Comment: @jsotola, disabling constant logging will increase the life of my SD card, as they have finite write cycles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Journald does potentially consume *a lot* of disk space compared to the traditional text based logging done by `rsyslog`.  In addition, since both are enabled by default in Raspbian, there is the implication that you will end up with redundant waste.

Fortunately, that's not quite how it is configured; from `/usr/share/doc/systemd/README.Debian`:

> To enable persistent logging, create /var/log/journal:
>
> mkdir -p /var/log/journal   systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix
> /var/log/journal
>
> systemd will make the journal files owned by the "systemd-journal"
> group and add an ACL for read permissions for users in the "adm"
> group.

This works because journald's default `Storage` mode is `auto`, meaning the logs will be kept in memory unless `/var/log/journal` or `/run/log/journal` exists<sup>1</sup> -- and they do not in the base image *[Later: They do in current versions]*. You will find these settings (`Storage`, etc.) in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`, and an explanation of them in `man journald.conf`; note that all of them are commented out, so journald policy defaults, explained in the man page, are used.

This means the `rsyslog` text records are unique.  That README (which is worth a browse) also notes that *"If you enable persistent logging, consider uninstalling rsyslog or any other system-log-daemon, to avoid logging everything twice."*

### Limiting text files

Storage of the text logs, created by rsyslog, can be controlled with `logrotate`; see `man logrotate` and `man logrotate.conf` (there's also no shortage of material online about it).  This rolls the files over, potentially compresses them, and discards based on volume and/or age.  Traditionally logrotate is executed by [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), but current Raspbian does it via a systemd timer (see `/etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/logrotate.timer`; check that it really is enabled with `systemctl status logrotate.timer`).

## Limiting journald

Journald has a conf file, `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`. All the settings there are (as mentioned above) commented out, but it can be configured to guarantee that **no disk space at all** is used regardless of whether `/var/log/journal` exists.  This is probably not desirable unless rsyslog, which writes the text files, is also running, so that there will at least potentially be some record left if the system crashes, if you want to compare current state to a previous point in time, etc.

To restrain journald, add this under `[Journal]` in the conf file:

```
Storage=volatile
RuntimeMaxUse=64M
```

This means the logs will be kept in memory with a 64 MB limit; entries are then discarded based on age (it may be more complicated than that, but it is mostly age).  You can play around to see how far back 64 MB will get you, but it is probably at least a couple of days.  `RuntimeMaxUse` applies only to logs in memory, but there is a parallel parameter for the "on disk" persistent storage, `SystemMaxUse`.

## Putting it together

So, that outlines two basic methodologies for logging with a size/time constrained permanent record:

1. Disable rsyslog, create `/var/log/journal` (if it doesn't exist already), set `SystemMaxUse` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`.
2. Set `Storage=volatile` in `jounrnald.conf`, leave rsyslog alone, and tailor `/etc/logrotate.conf`(and `/etc/logrotate.d/*`, from which it sources) to your liking.

The latter is the default scenario on Raspbian, but the logrotate configuration does not set any size constraints, only time based ones (to do that, see the doc references for logrotate above).

---

1. `/run/log/journal` would actually just be in memory too, as `/run` is a tmpfs filesystem.  But it would give you additional access.

Comment: B.t.w., the journal is only kept in memory by default. Because I don't need older logs I just do `apt --autoremove purge rsyslog`.

Comment: @Ingo That journald.conf tweak is something I've been doing whenever I set a new system up from the start, so if the default (on Raspbian) is already `volatile` then I would not have noticed (it certainly wasn't that when I first figured this out, but that would have been on a big fedora box).  *However*: Since there's no configuration done on Raspbian (`journald.conf` is all comments), I think the default (as per `man journald.conf`) is probably `auto`, meaning it will write to disk if a `/[var|run]/log/journal` directory exists, otherwise it is in memory...

Comment: ... and the default `RuntimeMaxUse` is 10% of total RAM.  `/[var|run]/log/journal` *don't* exist in the Raspbian base image, so you are right.

Comment: Do you know `/usr/share/doc/systemd/README.Debian`?

Comment: I did not (almost everything in /usr/share/doc/ is just changelogs and such).  But it certainly confirms this -- thank you, I will edit that in here.

Comment: This is a very good answer - thanks. I was alarmed when I learned how much space on the SD card is used by `journalctl` (`$ journalctl --disk-usage`). I don't know how @Ingo concluded it was *"only kept in memory"* - but perhps he was referring to `rsyslog` instead of `journald`? On my RPiLite bullseye, the defaults have not been changed (by me intentionally), but the cmd above reports `Archived and active journals take up 312.1M in the file system.` And since it seems impossible/impractical to disable `journald` I'm considering a class action lawsuit :)

Comment: Oh - forgot to mention that `var/log/journal` & `run/log/journal` both exist on my system. If I didn't create them, I wonder how they got there?

Comment: @Seamus I checked and `/var/log/journal` does exist in a current image (`/run/...` does not because  `/run` is a tmpfs mount, but on a running system it could).  Although I try not to say anything unless I am sure of it (or else qualify w/ "I think", "most likely" etc), and that seems like the kind of fact that would be easy to check, I kind of think they were always there.  Maybe.  Anyway, I've edited this to reflect that.

Comment: @goldilocks: OK, great - thanks again. ICYI:  I asked [a related Q on U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704833/why-can-journald-not-be-disabled). It seemed *off-topic* here in RPi SE, but if you've got an answer I'd love to hear it :)  Oh - please excuse the comment cesspool; my "old friend" Marcus is at it again - I've flagged it, but when I last checked it hasn't been cleaned up by the mods.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to reduce the potential for SD card corruption, then you should look at Adafruits tutorial for a "Read Only Raspberry Pi" -
https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/adafruits-read-only/
It is not perfect, but it will stop all logging and seems to survive most inadvertent power failures.